# Drupal 6 Restrict Taxonomy Terms with respect to domain

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am having Single Vocabulary with some terms defined say:

```
Term A
-- Term A Child
Term B
-- Term B Child
Term C
-- Term C Child
```

Also I have installed Domain Access module for multi-domain setup. I am having 3 domains sharing user and content pool.

Now I want to restrict these terms to be accessible while creating nodes.

Say for example1.com I want only Term A and their child terms to be accessible and example2.com only Term B and sub terms and so on.

Please guide me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is Domain Taxonomy Module: term editing forms are extended by new options for choosing domains where term must be published.

Thanks to Drupal IRC (channels : #drupal - dekita - David Thomas)